# How to make my select option absolute and top of card element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a input tag that can search skills. when i type, the option bar will be under the profile card.

```
 i want to make my select option on top of the profile card. [![select option box under the profile card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E724.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E724.png)

here is my css code for select option box:
`
.hover {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 400px;
        width:300px;
        overflow: auto;
        position: absolute;
        display:block;
    }
`
im trying to make my select option box on top of the profile card
```

Comment: You need to add `z-index of Search Input` is greater than `z-index of Profile Card`.
If it does not work, can you provide me your code (HTML, CSS) of `Search Input` and `Profile Card` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index`
The `z-index` prioritizes the stacking of elements.
Give the select option a higher `z-index` than the card element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add css property **z-index** to the expended box.

eg. `z-index: 12;`